# git diff --check shows changes of unrelated branch/files

Tags: git, whitespace, git-diff, git-log

#### Background

I am trying to see the whitespace errors of the current branch (ignoring **CR**
at eol).  Most files use **CRLF**, and I don't have the **core.whitespace**
config set.

This is the original command:

```
git -c core.whitespace=trailing-space,cr-at-eol diff --check master..HEAD
```

**HEAD** refers to a branch created on top of an older version of **master**
("**oldmaster**").

The problem is that `git diff --check` is behaving in an unexpected way: it is
showing not only the errors in **master..HEAD**, but also the errors in
**oldmaster..master**.

#### Questions

- Is this occurring because `git diff --check` compares the whole snapshots in
  the given revision range?
- Why do `git log` and `git diff` behave differently in this case?
- Shouldn't `git diff --check` compare only the changed lines in the changed
  files?

#### Information

**master** vs **oldmaster** (the numbers are coincidental):

```
$ git log --oneline oldmaster..master | wc -l
115

$ git diff --name-only oldmaster..master | wc -l
115
```

This shows the relevant commits correctly:

```
$ git log --oneline master..HEAD | wc -l
4
```

This shows the correct files:

```
$ git log --oneline --name-only master..HEAD -- | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z]+/' \
  | sort -u | wc -l
4
```

These for some reason also include the files changed in **oldmaster..master**:

```
$ git diff --name-only master..HEAD -- | wc -l
119

$ git -c core.whitespace=trailing-space,cr-at-eol diff --name-only \
  master..HEAD -- | wc -l
119
```

Both of these also show unrelated files:

```
$ git diff --check master..HEAD -- | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z]+/' | cut -d : -f 1 \
  | sort -u | wc -l
30

$ git -c core.whitespace=trailing-space,cr-at-eol diff --check master..HEAD \
  -- | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z]+/' | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u | wc -l
9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for combined diffs (which you are not using here), `git diff` strictly compares two *snapshots*.<sup>1</sup>  The syntax used—`git diff A B` vs `git diff A..B`—is irrelevant here.  Git extracts snapshot A, extracts snapshot B, and compares those two snapshots.  Any flag options you use, such as `--check`, are applied to this particular comparison.  Commit `A` need not be an ancestor of `B`, nor vice versa; Git does not look at any of the commits "between" these two commits; it simply extracts `A`, then extracts `B`, and diffs those.<sup>2</sup>

The `git log` command does something very different: it *walks the revision graph*.  Given `git log A..B`, Git finds all commits *reachable from* `B` that are not *reachable from* `A`.  For a clear definition of reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Note that when using `-p` with `git log` to view commits as patches, `git log` compares each commit to its (single) parent.  If there are three commits in the `A..B` range, for instance, `git log -p A..B` first shows `B` and runs `git diff B^ B`, then shows `B^` and runs `git diff B^^ B^`, and last shows `B^^` and runs `git diff B^^^ B^^`.  (This assumes there are no merge commits in the range, but `git log` omits patches for merge commits by default anyway.)

---

<sup>1</sup>To see a combined diff, use `git show` on a merge commit.  The `git diff` command will also produce combined diffs with some particular arguments, sometimes incorrectly: in particular the *three*-dot syntax, `git diff A...B`, is meant to compare the merge base of `A` and `B` to commit `B`, but sometimes does something different.  Also, when you are using the index and the index contains a conflicted merge, plain `git diff` will produce combined diffs.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, it does not even have to extract the two snapshots—it just works directly from their tree objects.  It does have to extract differing blobs, in order to compute the difference.  For identical blobs, `git diff` knows they are identical because their hash IDs match.  But it's easier to reason about this as "extract and compare".

Comment: Now it all makes sense. I did not know about `git log -p`; I managed to get the diffs that I wanted with it, thanks.